# Creating An Empty ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages Project

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm at starter level for for ASP.NET Core. I have some html pages crafted by `HTML5` and `CSS3`. I want show this pages with `ASP.NET` Core Razor Pages. So, I opened a new empty ASP.NET Core Project (Default is razor page I think.)

I copied the images and CSS file to `wwwroot` folder. Lastly, I copied my html codes into a new Razor Page (Main.cshtml) which is in "/Pages" folder. The page can see the CSS, the CSS can see the images. However, Edge gives `404 error` while running the project. I think I cannot do the routing correctly:

[image: 404 error]

[image: Code]

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access your razor page you will have to use the following url:

```
http://localhost:50551/Main
```

if you want to create a razor page which will be the default page for a domain, you should give it the name index.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks @pitaridis :)

Answer (score 1):

Write This Code To Your Startup

1-in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "{*url}");
});
```

2-in Configure:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Explain it please.